# How to get the querystring of a page with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I wanna to get the query string of a page within a JavaScript block.
for example:

The page has a URL like `localhost:1234/Test/page1.aspx?ID=10`

How can I get '10' with JavaScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`window.location.search` is the way to go.

Here's an example function:

```
function getQSVar( varname ) { 
   var query = window.location.search.substring( 1 ); 
   var vars = query.split( "&" );
   var len = vars.length; 
   for ( var i = 0; i < len; i++ ) { 
      var pair = vars[ i ].split( "=" ); 
      if ( pair[ 0 ] == varname ) { 
         return pair[ 1 ]; 
      } 
   } 
   return null;
}
```

Usage:

```
var IDValue = getQSVar( 'ID' ); // 10
```

Comment: You might want to split on /[&;]/ instead.

Comment: @Jacob Relkin How do I pass it to a textbox on an aspx page?